# Dash Home Not Working

Tags: unity-dash

Forgive my stupid question, but I just can't seem to get this working.  Upgraded to 11.10, but now when I click on Dash Home, the launcher goes translucent, but nothing else happens--no applications, no search pane, not even a blank dash home window.  Can anyone help?

Also, what is "daemon?"

Like I said--stupid questions.  Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: You can try to run `unity --reset` in a terminal to reset the settings.

Comment: For future reference, please ask only one question per post. Thanks!

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned and unanswered, could you perhaps add more detail to your question? If this question no longer applies then you can either delete it or answer it yourself if you've solved the problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Try `unity --reset` in a terminal.

Answer (score 1):

A "daemon" is the term for any process running in the background on your computer providing a service.  See the Wikipedia page for a full discussion:
    [http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daemon_(computing)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daemon_%28computing%29)