# No applications found in the Dash Home

Tags: unity, lenses

Running 12.04: When I go to the Dash Home, it shows no applications, anywhere, including the Applications lens.

I would include a screenshot, but I apparently need at least 10 reputation in order to do that.

I've looked around the site and tried several things (reinstalling [zeitgeist and unity](https://askubuntu.com/questions/181432/all-the-application-are-gone-from-the-dash-home),and [resetting unity](https://askubuntu.com/questions/114655/dash-home-not-working).

Any help?

Comment: I don't know what else to do, guys.
If need more information, lemme know.

Comment: Does this help? http://askubuntu.com/a/589189/72216 Mind that for 12.04, resetting Unity is different, see: http://askubuntu.com/questions/17610/how-do-i-reset-my-unity-configuration/202020#202020