# Searching a application name returns "sorry no match" in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04

All was working well in my Ubuntu 14.04. Suddenly I couldnt search any apps through search (by pressing super key).

I used to type "Terminal" or "System Monitor" and it would display those apps. But now, when I typed "Terminal" and any other apps like Chromium, it displays "sorry no match found". How to resolve this?

I can open System Monitor by pressing Alt + F2 and using the command `gnome-system-monitor`.

Comment: If you run in a terminal `com.canonical.Unity.Lenses disabled-scopes` what is the output?

Comment: it says command not found

Comment: @JacobVlijm do you mean `gsettings get com.canonical.Unity.Lenses disabled-scopes`?

Comment: and now it shows,... @as []

Comment: Try this: install `dconf-editor` (this saves entering a lot of long commands). Open `dconf-editor` and open the key `com.canonical.unity.lenses`. On the right-hand panel, click on each of the keys and click the button "Restore defaults". This should restore your search settings.

Comment: tried it. But "Set to Default" button is hidden on all the keys.

Comment: @Jos Ah, shoot, thanks, posted obviously in too much a hurry :)

Comment: Does this help: http://askubuntu.com/questions/17610/how-do-i-reset-my-unity-configuration/202020#202020

Comment: @JacobVlijm You could post this as an answer (with link provided as source) would help this out. :)

Answer (score 3):

#### Accidentally changed settings?

It could be that you accidentally changed the default search settings in Dash. I would check two things first:

1. run:

   ```
   gsettings get com.canonical.Unity.Lenses home-lens-default-view
   ```

   This should return a list, in which applications should appear, like:

   ```
   ['applications.scope', 'files.scope']
   ```

   If not, you can set it to default by the command:

   ```
   gsettings set com.canonical.Unity.Lenses home-lens-default-view "['applications.scope', 'files.scope']"
   ```
2. The applications Lens might be disabled for some reason, to check:

   ```
   gsettings get com.canonical.Unity.Lenses disabled-scopes
   ```

   It should return:

   ```
   @as []
   ```

   If not, reset it by:

   ```
   gsettings set com.canonical.Unity.Lenses disabled-scopes "[]"
   ```

#### If that doesn't work

If all fails, as an alternative, you can reset the Unity configuration [as described here](https://askubuntu.com/a/202020/72216):

1. You'll need `Unity Tweak Tool`:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install unity-tweak-tool
   ```
2. Run the command:

   ```
   unity-tweak-tool --reset-unity
   ```

Comment: @Anbu if this solved your problem (as you mentioned in a comment), would you consider accepting the answer? It creates clarity and makes sure the question does not seem unanswered.